# what's the fastest way to fill a table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, qtsql

I'm writing an application which produces a lot of data to store in a database.

The DB schema is very simple: it's a table with just 4 columns, but I must fill it with more than 30000 rows.

I'm using SQLite and QSql as API.

Data is produced very fast (no sleeps) and I'm using QSqlQuery to insert a row at time.
However it seems that it takes 7-8 seconds to store 100 rows (I'm using `QTime` for time counting).

I tried using `QSqlTableModel` but I noticed no performance improvements, even calling `QSqlTableModel::submitAll` every 1000 rows (`QTime` shows 70-80 seconds for 1000 rows).

Is there any way to store rows faster? What is the fastest way to fill a table with SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try looking at whether you've got [transactions set up correctly](http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html#transactions); they're expensive because they have to sync to disk to commit.

Also bear in mind that SQLite is more heavily optimized for reading anyway.

Comment: I had to use "COMMIT" instead of "END" but it worked: indeed it was a transaction related problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might try dropping any indexes at the start and then adding them back after all records have been imported. Results will vary of course if you're emptying the table first or just appending new records.